# How to compare values in different rows and different columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I've got the below data set, and need to get it to a level where it shows one line per day, per person, per product ID. With the end goal being able to compare the first previousStat based on tranTime with the most recent currentStat.

```
    tranDate    productID   tranTime    previousSTAT    currentSTAT     FIRSTNAME
    20140221    47444       10533900    NULL               U             SHAUN                         
    20140221    47444       10553700    U                  U             SHAUN                         
    20140304    47444       11133300    U                  U             TIMOTHY                       
    20140304    47444       11204900    U                  U             TIMOTHY
    20140305    47444       9133300     U                  Y             TIMOTHY                       
    20140305    47444       9204900     Y                  Y             TIMOTHY
```

As per the below:

```
    tranDate    productID       previousSTAT    currentSTAT     FIRSTNAME
    20140221    47444           NULL               U             SHAUN 
    20140304    47444           U                  U             TIMOTHY                                           
    20140305    47444           U                  Y             TIMOTHY
```

Any help that people can provide would be appreciated.

Regards,
Gabbaii

Comment: Just do the `Group By ` on the columns which you required like `select  ... from .. where ... Group by trandate,productID,previousstat,currentstat,firstname`

Comment: The example isn't the best possible because it doesn't explain how tranTime affects things, but if you're on SQL Server 2012 or newer the LAG -function could help you.

Comment: tranTime indicates when a transaction has taken place. So at an end state I want to compare the first previousStat value with the last currentStat value.

Comment: So, which version of SQL Server is it?

Comment: @dean SQL server 2008

Comment: @GaBBaii OK, for 2008 use what Hedley suggested. In 2012/2014 there is a more performant solution, with single pass through data instead of two, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about assigning row numbers to each group you are interested in, so that row number one represents the first line? Then do the same again but with the reverse ordering so that row number one represents the last line. Then join these two tables together. Something like:

```
With minvalues as
(Select tranDate,productId, previousStat, firstname, row_number() 
over (partition by tranDate,productId, firstname order by tranTime asc as rownum)
With maxvalues as
(Select tranDate,productId, currentStat, firstname, row_number() 
over partition by tranDate,productId,firstname order by tranTime desc as rownum)
Select min.tranDate,min.productId,min.Previousstat, max.currentStat, min.firstname
From minvalues as min inner join maxvalues as max
on min. tranDate = max.tranDate 
and min.productId = max.productId 
and min.firstname = max.firstname 
and min.rownum = 1 
and max.rownum = 1
```

Comment: You sir/madam, are amazing! I would kiss you right now if I could! I've been at this problem for a day or so, and it's been driving me nuts. Thank you so much!